# How to append one component to another dyinamically?

Tags: angular

I have some components DOM on the page:

```
<app-alert #type1 type="1"></app-alert>
<app-alert #type2 type="2"></app-alert>
<app-alert #type3 type="3"></app-alert>
```

Could I manage them ordering? Move `#type1` into `#type2` and `#type3` into `#type2`?

Or better to use recursive components?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this approach:

In app-alert component html you put this tag `<ng-content></ng-content>`

Then you can use it like this:

```
<app-alert #type1 type="1">

  <app-alert #type2 type="2">

    <app-alert #type3 type="3"></app-alert>

  </app-alert>

</app-alert>
```

You can read more in this [blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/).

Comment: I need to do that dinamicly, I have object with rules, which one component should be inside another

Comment: Could you extend you answer, it is not clear why you did this manually

Comment: Component `<app-alert>` has own content

Comment: Aha, dynamically, then use this approach: dynamic component loader:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 0):

You have recursive problem. If you don't want to use recursive components, you can use recursive ng-template references. You can find explain with example here: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3512-playing-with-recursive-ng-template-references-in-angular-6-1-10.htm

But for me, it is clearer for me to use recursive components.